Python fedora Visual Studio Code ( can't open file [Errno 2] No such file or directory )
I installed via rpm (not flatpak) visual studio code on fedora and cant run anything as simple as print("hello") because it says:
/bin/python: can't open file '/home/andre/code/print(hello).py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Did the same thing on my windows 11 VSC and everything just works as intended, so don't know what i am doing wrong here, btw just learning python and VSC
enter image description here

Does the file it is looking for exist? Did you try installing using Flatpack instead and see if this resolves things?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

if you're trying to run python code directly as an argument from command line, use the -c option: python -c 'print(hello)'. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27157683/how-to-use-the-c-flag-in-python
